# Calculating the value of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from a moment generating function.

Tags: probability, variance, means, moment-generating-functions

[image]

Find the moment generating function for X if $f(x) = 2x$ , $0 < x < 1 $. Then, use the moment generating function to find $\mu_{x}$ and $\sigma_{x}^{2}$.

I calculated and found the value of MGF or moment generating function. Its $M.G.F. = [2e^{t}/t - 2e^{t}/t^{2} + 2/t^{2}]$ which is correct I know. How am I supposed to find the rest two?

I used a concept where I have $N(\mu,\sigma)$, and so you let $Z = (X - \sigma)/\mu$, then since our function is from 0 to 1, therefore we should be having $N(0,1)$ which means $\mu = 0$, and $\sigma = 1$. So, you get $Z = X$ which is basically the same thing. I got confused there. Also, I was thinking whether to find mean and variance of r.v. X. Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: As the name suggests, the moment generating function can be used to generate the moments.  So $M_X(t) = 1 + \mathbb E[X] t+\frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{2!}t^2+\frac{\mathbb E[X^3]}{3!}t^3+\cdots$ and either Taylor series or taking derivatives will give you  $\mathbb E[X]$  and $\mathbb E[X^2]$

Comment: I know how to find out mean (i.e. $E[X]$) and Var (i.e. ($E[X^2] - E[X])^2$). What I don't understand is how to get $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$.

Comment: $\mu=E[X]$ and $\sigma^2=Var(X)$.

Comment: Ok, got it then. I was thinking the same thing but then I thought it wont be due to the nature of the problem which is a different one. Thanks anyway. I will do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the moment generating function is 
\begin{align}
M_X(t) &= \mathbb E[e^{tX}]\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{tx}f_X(x)\ \mathsf d x\\
&= \int_0^1 2xe^{tx}\ \mathsf dx\\
&=\frac 2{t^2}(1 - e^t (1 - t))
\end{align}
We can compute the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ moment of $X$ by $\mathbb E[X^n]=\lim_{t\to 0}M_X^{(n)}(t)$. For $n=1$, this is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X] &= \lim_{t\to 0}M_X'(t)\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac2{t^3}(t^2e^t -2 te^t +2 e^t-2)\\
&=\frac23,
\end{align}
and for $n=2$ this is
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X^2] &= \lim_{t\to 0}M_X''(t)\\
&=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac 2{t^4}(t^3e^t -3t^2 e^t +6 t e^t-6 e^t+6)\\
&= \frac12.
\end{align}
Hence 
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2 = \frac 12 - \left(\frac 23\right)^2 = \frac1{18}.
$$

Comment: yeah got it man, nice one. But for n = 2, its $E[X^{2}]$ and not $E[X]$. Anyway, its correct I did it few mins ago.

Comment: Oh, I fixed the typo.

Comment: ok cool. Now, it looks perfect.